# passing and using an object by value vs reference for out of memory exception

Tags: c#, memory, reference, compilation, out-of-memory

Lets say i have some large object.  I pass this object into a function to be used.  Would calling doSomthingRef actually prevent the object from being copied again, potentially reducing the chance of the OOM exception?

Example:

```
HugeObject ho = new HugeObject();

private void doSomthing1(HugeObject h)
{
 var value = h.value;
 if (h.conditional) {finalStep(value);}
}


private void doSomthingRef(ref HugeObject refh)
{
 if (refh.conditional) {finalStep( ref refh.value);}
}

int finalStep (TypeOfValue value)
{
//magic
}

int finalStep (ref TypeOfValue value)
{
//magic
}
```

Comment: @Forklift: Only if the parameter is a reference type (derived from Object).

Comment: @ H.G. My point is that the HugeObject is not being copied when passed as a parameter. The only advantage to passing by ref would be if you wanted to change HugeObject and continue to use it. Since, in the snippet above, the value is just being evaluated, it would not change the memory usage.

Comment: @Forklift Objects are only ever passed by value unless `out` or `ref` is used.  Adding `ref` doesn't "make it explicit", it changes the semantics from passing a copy of the value to passing a reference to the variable.  Of course, for a reference type, the value itself *is* a reference, rather than an actual object instance.

Comment: @servy, you're right that was not clear or helpful. However, it is still true that with or without `ref`, the only thing being passed is a reference and not an object for this HugeObject.

Comment: @Forklift That is correct.

Comment: @servy so passing by reference here would avoid copying the object into memory again, whereas passing by value would create another copy, correct?

Comment: @adamkim No.  Neither method is going to create a new instance of the object.  One method allows you to access the one existing object instance, the other lets you read *or change* the variable that references it, allowing you to change *what object it references* rather than just accessing the object itself.

Comment: @servy just so i'm clear. the line 
 var value = h.value;
does not make a new copy of value so it does not save any memory vs the method that I use the pass by reference?  I thought when you pass by value you are actually making a new copy for that method to work with?

Comment: @adamkim If the type of `h.value` is a value type, then the value is copied, if it's a reference type, then a copy of a reference to that object is made.  In either case, some memory is used; either the memory for the value itself, or if it's a reference type, the memory for the reference.